# Samsung galaxy S10+ Crash report on Play Store

Tags: android, android-10.0, samsung-galaxy

Do we have any workaround/solution to fix as we are seeing many crash reports on play store?

Samsung Galaxy S10+ (beyond2q), 7680MB RAM, Android 10

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping (ActivityThread.java:5002)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600 (ActivityThread.java:267)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2079)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7762)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Comment: not your problem. read https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=365613&listLines=40&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=ALL&searchText=hand

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya but that thread stared on  Mar 11, 2019, but still, they didn't fix this issue. How irresponsible #Samsung.

Comment: Feel your situation. Contact https://us.account.samsung.com/accounts/v1/SD/signInGate?response_type=code&client_id=x1a86ah5j4&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Fdeveloper.samsung.com%2Fsa%2Fsignin%2Fcallback&state=VmpKMGIxTXlSa2hWV0d4V1lteHdjRlJVU2xOT2JHUlhXVE5vYTJKVldrcFdWbEYzVUZFOVBR&goBackURL=https:%2F%2Fdeveloper.samsung.com

Comment: Posted on Samsung developer forum https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/samsung-s10-crashes-on-play-store/2642

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Samsung Specific Issue. People are facing similar crashes. A thread has been opened on Samsung Forum mentioning the exact same issue. Currently, no workaround is available as it is unknown why it's happening. Keep an eye on the thread, Samsung may come up with a workaround on that thread.

My guess is it is happening due to their Battery Saving Strategy.